# Is updating with inline select atomic in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have an app that calculates points for a user, based on certain rules, for every dollar they spent on my portal. I am using the following stored procedure to update the points of the user:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Update_Points`;    
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Update_Points` (
pUserId BIGINT,
pPoints DECIMAL(13,2), // points accrued for the amount 'pAmount'
pAmount DECIMAL(13,2) // amount spent by the user
)

SPROC:BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RESIGNAL;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO AuditTable(UserId, Amount, Points)
    VALUES (pUserId, pAmount, pPoints);

    UPDATE PlayerPoints
    SET Points = Points + pPoints
    WHERE UserId = pUserId;
    
    SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @RowsUpdated;

    COMMIT;

    SELECT @RowsUpdated;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am seeing discrepancies in total points accrued by some of the users. I know this because we have another backend database that stores user transactions.

We have multiple instances of our applications running to handle the load so one idea was that it could this stored procedure that could cause the accrued points discrepancy, based on the idea that the following snippet might not be `atomic`

```
UPDATE PlayerPoints
    SET Points = Points + pPoints
    WHERE UserId = pUserId;
```

So my question to you gurus of mysql is whether the above `UPDATE` statement is atomic or not?

The `PlayerPoints` table has following structure:

| UserId | Amount | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 50 |
| 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 35 | 30 |
| 3 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 35 | 30 |

Comment: Yes, it is atomic.

Comment: @Akina Can you point me to some mysql documentation that confirms that? Or is that a fundamental understanding in mysql?

Comment: AFAIR this was described in details in Reference manual to MySQL version 4 in General info - Compilance. Now I cannot find the same in the documentation.

Comment: what about this then https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html ?

Comment: I think that this is unrelated. I'll try to translate from the translation: *Transaction support in the MySQL server is implemented using the InnoDB and BDB transactional table handlers (see section 7 MySQL Table Types). InnoDB tables are designed to meet the requirements of the ACID.*

Comment: *However, for tables of non-transactional types, such as MyISAM, MySQL uses a different data integrity paradigm, called "atomic operations". Atomic operations versus transactions often provide the same or even better integrity with higher performance. Since the MySQL server supports both paradigms, the user can choose between the speed that atomic operations provide and the transactional capabilities for their applications. This choice can be made for each table separately.*